# Error while exanding navigator contents

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am facing this error each time the node is expanded. I am not getting how to solve this
 org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: No property tester contributes a property org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature to type class custom.object which implements IAdaptable.

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">
  <navigatorContent
        activeByDefault="true"
        appearsBefore="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resourceContent"
        contentProvider="custom.content.provider.HistoryContentProvider"
        id="custom.content.history"
        labelProvider="custom.provider.HistoryLabelProvider"
        name="History Tree"> 
     <possibleChildren>
         <or>
            <instanceof
                  value="custom.model.IHistoryNode">
            </instanceof>
            <instanceof
                  value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
            </instanceof>
         </or>
        </possibleChildren>
     <triggerPoints>
        <or>
           <adapt
                 type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
              <test
                    args="org.eclipse.team.core.repository,org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnnature"
                    property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectPersistentProperty">
              </test>
           </adapt>
           <instanceof
                 value="custom.model.IDcmSVNHistoryNode">
           </instanceof>
        </or>
     </triggerPoints>

      </navigatorContent>
```

Comment: Expanding what navigator content? Is this something you have coded? There is nowhere near enough information here to give any sort of answer.

Comment: Sorry for improper information. I have contributed to Project explorer using navigator content binding.

Comment: I don't see any references to custom.object or the project nature property tester in this